# UIScrollView with Large Image

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

This code shows the scrollView, but image I want shown (tutorial) is larger than the view. In other words tutorial.png is exactly 280X1200 but it won't aspectFit. I'm missing something small here:

```
tipScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 1200)];
tipScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
tipScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
tipScroll.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIImageView *tutorialImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorial"]];

tipScroll.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
tutorialImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

tipScroll.contentSize = tutorialImageView.frame.size;

[self.view addSubview:tipScroll];
[tipScroll addSubview:tutorialImageView];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at the below edited code.It will work

```
tipScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 1200)];
tipScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
tipScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
tipScroll.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIImageView *tutorialImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 1200)];
tutorialImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorial"];

tipScroll.contentSize = tutorialImageView.frame.size;
[tipScroll addSubview:tutorialImageView];
[self.view addSubview:tipScroll];
```